# html5 audio crashes on seeking

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, html, audio

I have a ASP.NET Application and I want to use the  tag to play music. 
In the codebehind I write this element

```
<audio controls preload src='PATH/TO/FILE'></audio>
```

into a literal.
The Problem is that the player crashes when I click in the seek bar at a position behind the current position.

There is no error message or any other response. It just stops working. I have to reload the page to get it working again.

Seeking forward just works fine with small files. With larger files (a song with about 2:00 min) the controls gets grey and nothing happens anymore until I click in the seekbar again nearby the starting position.

When I create a simple HTML File with nothing else than this audio tag the seeking works.

I'm using Chrome v. 26.

I have no idea why this is not working in the ASP.NET application...

The next problem is that I can't use something like soundmanager2 oder jPlayer. I used soundmanager2 before but I had many problems with it.

In the test above I just use one sound file with the audio tag but in the final state there will be a couple of players.

the sound files are created dynamically and so are the players and this happens with ajax. I had to recreate the soundmanager2 object every time and there occurred several problems.

So my hope is that somebody maybe has an idea why the audio tag is not working correctly in the ASP.NET application or give me a hint to something how I can achieve it to have multiple audio players on one page which changes dynamically per ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found it...
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306127/issue-with-html5-audio-control-in-visual-studio-2010-and-asp-net-mvc) helped me

The problem was that the path of the sound file was on localhost. 
After i uploaded it to a server and used that url it worked.

I think that the reason it worked with the simple HTML testfile was because i used an absolute Path there to the wavfile.